# Telegram sharing PDF file with its front page as link

Tags: telegram

I want to share a PDF file of a book in a telegram group.

First of all, I like to make the front page of the book as a visible icon for the download link.

Second, I want to add an explanation under the link.

How can I do?

Please help and guide.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use your explanation for all you want with some robots, such as `@binambot` Telegram bot.

But unfortunately there is no way to show the first page of a PDF file in telegram automatically. You can get a shot from the first page manually and send it as a separate picture.